# Find max column value across multi csv files in R

Tags: r, csv, minimax

Thank you for reading this.

I am trying to find the max value of one column from data across 2 CSV files (see file example below).

**Not sure how to find the max value of a particular column (tp,)**

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be better if you split your question into two different questions e.g. one question for "how to open files", and another question on finding the max.
Also, it would be good to read guidelines on creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine both the files and find max.

```
df1 <- read.csv("Path to the file1", header=T, sep=",")
df2 <- read.csv("Path to the file2", header=T, sep=",")
data <- rbind(df1,df2)
max(data['temp'])
```

In case you have many files,

```
setwd('Path of the folder that contains the files')   
filenames <- list.files(full.names=TRUE)
data <- lapply(filenames,function(i){read.csv(i)})
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, data)
max(df['temp'])
```

Comment: There is no need to apply rbind. You can directly find the max value by 
max(df1$col1, df2$col2)